# Format option on ctrl+A in visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Like what we do in Visual  Web Developer, there is an icon which says to format the currently selected text, but what to do the same in visual studio c# being creating a desktop application.
Waiting for your responses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl+K followed by Ctrl+F will apply formatting to the selected code.

You can define formatting and spacing settings in Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting.

Edit: you can find the list of all shortcuts on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Press `Control + E, Control + F` to format the currently selected text.